# Is there a way to use GreenSock (GSAP) to animate an SVG component in React?

Tags: reactjs, animation, gsap

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { ReactComponent as Petri } from './petri-dish.svg';

const App = () => {

    return (
        <svg>
            <Petri />
        </svg>
    );
}
export default App;
```

I have imported the svg as a React component (Petri). I haven't been able to find any examples to help me animate that component with GSAP. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't put code in an image, put it as text with code formatting.

Comment: Welcome @Marik, please can you format the code so its easier for users to follow.

Comment: SVG is no different than any other DOM elements. https://greensock.com/react should be able to help, though the syntax used is from GSAP 2.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a `forwardRef` for the svg component and then manipulate as needed using the `.current` property.

See the minimal example below:

```
const SVG = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <svg ref={ref} version="1.1" id="svg" className="container" width="260" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 260 200" >
      <rect id="svgRectangle" className="animated" x="20" y="60" width="220" height="80" fill="#91e600"/>
    </svg>
));

function App() {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      TweenLite.to(svgRef.current, 2, {opacity: 0});
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <SVG ref={svgRef} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/65jrcgfw/19/)